# Update successive rows from a dataset

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to update EffectiveEndDTM in the first row from NULL to LoadDTM value from the second row and similarly for all the rows except the last one which will remain NULL.

```
EffectiveStartDTM       EffectiveEndDTM CurrentRecInd   LoadID  LoadDTM
2016-06-13 13:05:09.000 NULL            1               130272  2016-06-13 13:05:09.000
2016-06-27 10:27:13.000 NULL            1               133819  2016-06-27 10:27:13.000
2016-07-04 10:05:23.000 NULL            1               135323  2016-07-04 10:05:23.000
2016-07-11 12:11:52.000 NULL            1               136943  2016-07-11 12:11:52.000
```

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2, sorry I missed mentioning that in the question.

Comment: `first`, `second`, `successive` and `last` have no meaning in SQL **unless you explcitly specify an `ORDER BY` clause**. What is your order by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @T As Table
(
    EffectiveStartDTM datetime,
    EffectiveEndDTM datetime,
    CurrentRecInd tinyint,
    LoadID int,
    LoadDTM datetime
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
('2016-06-13 13:05:09.000', NULL, 1, 130272, '2016-06-13 13:05:09.000'),
('2016-06-27 10:27:13.000', NULL, 1, 133819, '2016-06-27 10:27:13.000'),
('2016-07-04 10:05:23.000', NULL, 1, 135323, '2016-07-04 10:05:23.000'),
('2016-07-11 12:11:52.000', NULL, 1, 136943, '2016-07-11 12:11:52.000')

;WITH cte
AS 
(
    SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LoadID) AS RowId
    FROM
        @T
)

SELECT
    A.LoadID,
    B.LoadDTM
FROM
    cte A LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT cte.RowId -1 AS RowId, cte.LoadDTM  FROM  cte
    ) B ON A.RowId = B.RowId
WHERE
    A.EffectiveEndDTM IS NULL
```

Output

```
LoadID  LoadDTM
130272  2016-06-27 10:27:13.000
133819  2016-07-04 10:05:23.000
135323  2016-07-11 12:11:52.000
136943  NULL
```

Update real table

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET EffectiveEndDTM = R.LoadDTM
FROM
(
    SELECT
       A.LoadID,
       B.LoadDTM
    FROM
        cte A LEFT JOIN 
        (
            SELECT cte.RowId -1 AS RowId, cte.LoadDTM  FROM  cte
        ) B ON A.RowId = B.RowId
    WHERE
        A.EffectiveEndDTM IS NULL
) R
WHERE
    YourTable.LoadID = R.LoadID
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it's 2008 r2, you can't use `lead` / `lag` functions that was introduced in 2012, but this doesn't mean you can't get the value of the next / prev row. You just need a subquery:

Create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions)

```
DECLARE @T As Table
(
    EffectiveStartDTM datetime,
    EffectiveEndDTM datetime,
    CurrentRecInd tinyint,
    LoadID int,
    LoadDTM datetime
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
('2016-06-13 13:05:09.000', NULL, 1, 130272, '2016-06-13 13:05:09.000'),
('2016-06-27 10:27:13.000', NULL, 1, 133819, '2016-06-27 10:27:13.000'),
('2016-07-04 10:05:23.000', NULL, 1, 135323, '2016-07-04 10:05:23.000'),
('2016-07-11 12:11:52.000', NULL, 1, 136943, '2016-07-11 12:11:52.000')
```

Update:

```
UPDATE T1
SET EffectiveEndDTM = (
    SELECT TOP 1 EffectiveStartDTM
    FROM @T T2
    WHERE T2.EffectiveStartDTM > T1.EffectiveStartDTM
    ORDER BY T2.EffectiveStartDTM
)
FROM @T T1
```

Test the update was successful:

```
SELECT EffectiveStartDTM, EffectiveEndDTM, CurrentRecInd, LoadID, LoadDTM
FROM @T
```

Results:

```
EffectiveStartDTM       EffectiveEndDTM         CurrentRecInd LoadID      LoadDTM
----------------------- ----------------------- ------------- ----------- -----------------------
2016-06-13 13:05:09.000 2016-06-27 10:27:13.000 1             130272      2016-06-13 13:05:09.000
2016-06-27 10:27:13.000 2016-07-04 10:05:23.000 1             133819      2016-06-27 10:27:13.000
2016-07-04 10:05:23.000 2016-07-11 12:11:52.000 1             135323      2016-07-04 10:05:23.000
2016-07-11 12:11:52.000 NULL                    1             136943      2016-07-11 12:11:52.000
```